# Can't use request 'get' in django

Tags: django

I am using django, and want to get simple 'get' request from server. It seems like view is taking it, and in console it have code '200'. But in view I try to check it someway, but I can't. Can somebody tell my what I am doing wrong.

This is my view:

```
def check_register(request):
    if request.GET.get("sign_mail"):
        return HttpResponse("YEAH, GET")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("no didn't")
```

My form:

```
<form action="/checkRegister/" method="GET">
<input class="header_input" type="text" size="25" name="sign_mail" placeholder="Email">
<button class="sign_btn" type="submit">ВОЙТИ</button>
</form>
```

My urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'$', views.index),
    url(r'^checkRegister/$', views.check_register),
]
```

Comment: What does the `request.GET` `QueryDict` contain?

Comment: http://localhost:8000/checkRegister/?sign_mail=lol%40inbox.ru

Comment: This is my url what I get. I've tried to check it using:
if request.method == "GET": print("lol")
But it don't print anything in console. And I don't know what is the problem

Comment: Try putting `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` inside your function - right above the line `if request.GET.get("sign_mail"):`. When the debugger catches there, enter `dir()`. What does that return? If you see a `request` object in there, what does entering `request.GET` return?

Comment: Post your `views.index`

Comment: def index(request):
    template = loader.get_template('index.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render())

Comment: @beluga.me Ohh, thank you! It works!